# Avoid HasData Seed DbContext in EF Core 2.2 during Unit Tests

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, xunit

In my ASP.Net CORE 2.2/EF Core 2.2 web API app, I have a HasData() method in my DbContext to seed the DB with some standard data that I use.  However, I don't want to use that data when running my xUnit tests.

My unit tests use the Sqlite in-memory provider and as part of that process, it requires a call to EnsureCreated().  Well, EnsureCreated() calls OnModelCreating() which calls HasData(), so my unit test context now contains all of my HasData seed data, which I don't want.  I want to seed my unit tests with different, very specific data.

Because EnsureCreated() seeds the context, and then I try adding my unit test specific seed data, I end up with both sets of data in my test DbContext and my tests fail.

How can I bypass the HasData call for my unit tests?

Comment: I also encountered this issue but can't find a way solve it. I just settled into using the InMemory Database Provider for some of my tests.

Comment: @PaoloGo, I started with the regular InMemory provider but ran into an issue with that because it doesn't reset the Identity increment between tests running in parallel, so I was getting unpredictable primary key IDs.

Comment: Ah also got issue on that lol. You can workaround by testing against the inserted entity's PK instead of a constant value. e.g. `var foo = ctx.Add(new Foo()); ... Assert.Equal(foo.Id, actualId);` Should be a non-issue on EF Core v3

Comment: Please let me know if you get a solution on the original issue though. We could open an issue on the repo otherwise :)

Comment: Another workaround for the original issue is to remove the seed explicitly e.g. `ctx.RemoveRange(ctx.Foo);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to bypass HasData(), you could instead conditionally not supply data to that method.

Quick example - if you move the pre-pop data out to e.g. "DataInitialiser" classes:

```
 builder.HasData(new UserDataInitialiser().Data);
```

Then set a static flag in a base class:

```
public abstract class DataInitialiserControl
{
    public static bool SkipInitData { get; set; } // ** flag **
}

public abstract class DataInitialiser<T> : DataInitialiserControl
{
    public IList<T> Data => SkipInitData ? new List<T>() : GetData();

    protected abstract IList<T> GetData();
}
```

Your DataInitialisers would look like this:

```
public class UserDataInitialiser : DataInitialiser<User>
{
    protected override IList<User> GetData()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new User {Id = 1, Name = "Bob"}
        };
    }
}
```

You could then just set the static flag in your test initialisation:

```
public abstract class TestBase
{
    protected DbContextOptions<MyContext> DbOptions { get; private set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeDatabase()
    {
        // ** SKIP DATA PRE-POP **
        DataInitialiserControl.SkipInitData = true;

        DbOptions = BuildDbContextOptions(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()).Options;

        using (var context = GetContext())
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void ClearDatabase()
    {
        using (var context = GetContext())
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        }
    }
}
```

(Code untested, but should be more or less right).

Answer (score 0):

You could always mock the call with `Mock` it will provides a way to mock an interface making it so the function calls of the said mocked interface will actually be calling your mocked function.  This will provide a way for you to override the function call to `HasData`.

Of course, this means if it isn't already using an interface for that function(s) you'll have to wrap it in one.

Here are a few useful examples to Mocking: [writing unit tests with NUnit and Moq](https://developerhandbook.com/unit-testing/writing-unit-tests-with-nunit-and-moq/) and [an introduction to unit testing with mocks(using moq)](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/08/07/intro-mocking-moq/).

I also suspect that Theory attribute and inline data could be of use to you.
    [Creating parameterized tests in xUnit](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/)

Hope that helps.